# Error changing element positioning to absolute with javascript

Tags: javascript, position, css-position

I tried to change the positioning of a div's child elements dynamically from static to absolute. I thought it would be as simple as:

```js
function positionToRelative_doesNotWork(e){
    const currentLeft =  e.offsetLeft
    const currentTop = e.offsetTop
    console.log(`(${currentLeft},${currentTop})`)
    e.style.left = currentLeft + 'px'
    e.style.top = currentTop + 'px'
    e.style.position = 'absolute'
}

document.querySelectorAll(selector).forEach((e)=>{
    positionToRelative_doesNotWork(e)
})
```

But, when I execute that code, all child elements ends at position (0,0). The above `console.log()` only prints (0,0) for all elements.

I've solved it with this workaround:

```js
function positionToRelative_works(e){
  const currentLeft =  e.offsetLeft
  const currentTop = e.offsetTop
  console.log(`(${currentLeft},${currentTop})`)
  e.style.left = currentLeft + 'px'
  e.style.top = currentTop + 'px'
  setTimeout(()=>{
    let elem = e
    elem.style.position = 'absolute'  
  },1)
}
```

I've tested it on Firefox and Chromium for Linux so I think it's not a browser's bug. You have an example [here](https://codepen.io/maceda/pen/poJVBBm)

I don't know why it works (and why the first version does not work) 
Any clues?

Comment: You never change the original position, i.e. the offsets keep zero.

Comment: Please, could you explain a little more? Why it works asynchronously but doesn't work synchronously? That's what I don't understand.